# Why did Apple change UITableViewCell working order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Nowadays we have to use this code somewhere in ViewDidLoad -

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and I am not sure what was wrong with old way by checking if cell was actually returned by queue in old method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

What confuses me, is why use some arbitary method calls in irrelevant places, and what does this "register" method does anyway?

Comment: You don't have to use `registerClass` or `registerNib` with table views, the "old way" still works. (Only with the new collection views you have to register a class or nib first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's since in iOS 5 that Apple introduced a short-cut method of instantiating cells from NIB files that has three stages:

1. Declaring a property for the cell identifier
2. Registering the NIB object that contains the cell, and associating that
   with the cell identifier
3. Creating the cell itself (and then customizing the controls as usual)

Registering the NIB object needs to happen only once during the lifetime of the controller, so an obvious place to put the code is in the `viewDidLoad` method of the tableView’s controller:

```
cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:nil]
```

This takes two parameters:

1. A reference to an instance of UINib, which you get by passing in
   UINib’s `nibWithNibName` method
2. The `NSString` cell identifier that was previously created

After the NIB is registered for use as a cell, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method will do one of two things:

1. If there’s a cached cell available for reuse, it will be dequeued
   and can be accessed through the cell variable.
2. If there isn’t a cell available for reuse,
   `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will create one from the
   registered NIB.

**Both of these things take place behind the scenes, so there’s now no longer any need to do the check for the cell’s existence manually**. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` **will handle all that for you**.